# Registro de usuario en Firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase

He creado esta función para registrar a los usuarios pero todo el rato salta al else diciendo que el correo y la contraseña no son válidos, aunque ponga los datos bien ¿Cómo podría ver lo que falla? Quizás es un error en la función pero no lo consigo localizar. La base de datos está totalmente vacía, no es que haya otro con el mismo usuario

```
private void register(final String username, final String fullname, String email, String password){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);

                        HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("id",userid);
                        hashMap.put("username",username.toLowerCase());
                        hashMap.put("fullname",fullname);
                        hashMap.put("bio","");
                        hashMap.put("imageurl","gs://blindchat2.appspot.com/userimage.jpg");

                        reference.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }else{
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"You can't register with this email or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Exception e = task.getException();
                        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());//E/TAG: The email address is badly formatted.



                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Depura tu código y revisa por qué está fallando. Prueba a poner esto en la parte del `else`: **`Exception e = task.getException();`**  y luego muestra un log del objeto `e` , cópialo y agrégalo a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código es correcto, el error estaba en que me equivoqué al pasarle la string al email y le estaba pasando el nombre del usuario.